# How to set a database in emergency mode?

Tags: sql-server, database

my database is stoped. i can't make anything, select, update, nothing.
somebody told me to set the database in emergency mode but i don't know how?

Comment: what kind of database? what is emergency mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the solution :
ALTER DATABASE dbName SET Emergency

Comment: this solutions set database in emergency mode. in this mode you can get all the data.

Answer (score 0):

i think this is only for Server DB, or not?

in SQL Documentation was a query like this:

```
set emergency mode "databasename"
```

try it on! cos' I have only Express Edition of SQL Server here

Answer (score 0):

If your databse is in suspect mode, you will have to keep that database in emergencey mode (to gain acesses to that DB).

```
alter database datasename set emergency
```

Then run DBCC statement as:

```
dbcc chedkdb(DBname,repair_rebuild) with no_infomsgs
```

If this doesnt work ,then keep the DB in singleuser mode like below and run checkdb statement

```
alter database DBname set single_user
dbcc checkdb(DBname,repair_allow_data_loss) with no_infomsgs
```

If that succeeds,now keep the DB online by

```
alter database DBname set multi_user
```

Answer (score 0):

```
USE [master] GO
-- Method 1: I use this method
EXEC sp_attach_single_file_db @dbname='TestDb',
@physname=N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDb.mdf'
GO
-- Method 2:
CREATE DATABASE TestDb ON
(FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\TestDb.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG
GO
```